# What does Enable Go modules integration do in Intellij IDE

Tags: go, intellij-idea

Not having previous knowledge about creating a project from zero within terminal, I've created a folder, cd into of it then run `go mod init my_project_name` which created a go.mod file for me, then I've created main.go file which built just ok.

Then I created a folder and add a go file inside with package name (being same with directory) and create a struct inside of it. Next I tried to import that package in main package but when I try to build on terminal it gave me this error

```
go: cannot determine module path for source directory /Users/berkcan/workspace/go/my_project_name (outside GOPATH, module path must be specified)
```

After googling and not being able to find a solution to my problem, I've imported project to beloved Intellij IDE and I enabled Go modules integration then everything worked flawlessly. First I thought IDE doing some magic inside while building project but even when I try `go build` command in terminal, it built. But I cant see difference in project structure or a new line in go.mod file.

So what happened, what did Intellij IDE did when I ticked go module integration box and what I can do enable it on terminal without Intellij IDE ?

[here is the photo of option in IDE when ticked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe53a.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA plus Go plugin or GoLand under the hood has two modes to get the information about your packages (simplified):

- GOPATH. IDEA scans your `$GOPATH` directory to build internal indexes of your packages and provides code completion, resolving, etc.
- Go Modules. IDEA executes `go list -m -json` to resolve your dependencies and scans your `$GOPATH/pkg/mod` directory (default value of `GOMODCACHE`) for the packages. If they don't exist, IDEA executes `go mod download`. After these operations, the IDE provides all built-in features like code completion, navigation and so on.

Both modes don't change your Go or environment variables as well as behavior in the terminal. When you check *Enable Go Modules integration* option in the settings, the IDE just switches the mode from scan `$GOPATH` to execute `go list` and resolve your dependencies from the Go Modules cache.

To summarize, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't do any magic. I suppose it relates to your custom Go environment variables inside the terminal, especially `GO111MODULE` and if you didn't pass these variables to the GUI apps (e.g. you have specified it in `.zshrc` file and run the IDE via Desktop entry instead of the terminal), IntelliJ IDEA doesn't inherit them. You can compare `go env` output inside your local terminal and built-in inside the IDE (*View | Tool Windows | Terminal*) and find differences.

Comment: Got it, when I compared two terminals, IDE terminal has GO111MODULE="on"
while in my terminal it is GO111MODULE="" but still I can build on my terminal too while thats still bugs me shouldnt I not be able to build on my terminal while go111module is looking empty